# How do I add/remove density colors on the Windows Universal App CalendarView control after loading?

Tags: xaml, widget, windows-10, win-universal-app, calendarview

`CalendarViewDayItemChanging` seems to be the way to add 'density colors' (coloured bars in a `DayItem` box) to a Windows Universal App `CalendarView`.

However `CalendarViewDayItemChanging` is only fired when the `DayItem` box is loaded i.e. on initial loading and possibly when navigating to a far enough date and back again such that the virtualisation re-loads the `DayItem`.

However when I create an appointment on the selected date I need to add a density color bar immediately, similarly if I remove an appointment, I need to remove that bar.

How do I get the control to reload or re-render that particular `DayItem`?

Notes:

- There is only the `SelectedDates` available as a property
- There is no obvious way to ge the `DayItem` collection
- Setting the `Visibility` to `Collapsed` then `Visible` instantaneously does not trigger a reload.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue on the MSDN blogs here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54c81ada-4147-474b-8425-524ec69bc749/uwp-calendarview?forum=wpdevelop

I think your best bet currently is to have your Appointment creation on a separate page and store a List of Appointments locally or in a db. That way when you navigate back to the Page with your calendar view you can reload the Calendar using the updated Appointment list.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MyCalendarView.UpdateLayout method to force the control to hit the CalendarViewDayItemChanging event again.
I called the method from the DataContextChanged event on my UserControl.  This way anytime I change the DataContext the density colors get updated.  This is sufficient for my needs.  It sounds like you want to do it on a different event.

```
private void UserControl_DataContextChanged(Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (this.DataContext is ObservableCollection<Event>)
        {
            eventCalendar.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
```